# Laragon Sites-Enables stopped working

Tags: nginx, dns, hosts, laragon

I have been learning the Laravel framework and I used Laragon to get started.  Laragon sets up my web server and my Hosts file so that I can access my work through the browser.  Normally, I would boot up the server using the fancy "Start" button in Laragon and then go to the browser and type in "myFirstApp.dev" and my site would show up.  Now I am getting an error in the browser that says "This site cannot be reached" (as shown in image1.jpg).  How can I fix/diagnose the issue?  Has anyone else ran in to this issue?

[image].

Comment: I tired opening this URL in Firefox and it worked!  This must be a Google Chrome issue.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question.  If anyone runs in to this same issue, here is an explanation.  Google released Chrome v63 which forces all .dev domains to https.  To fix this either enable SSL in Laragon or chance the domain extension your projects (.test for example).  This will require changing your hosts and {Laragon Root}\etc\nginx\sites-enabled files.

https://forum.laragon.org/topic/761/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-to-https/6